# How to do dynamic string formatting of the text for a web button control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, vb.net, button

I am working on creating dynamic text for an asp.net button server control.

```
<asp:Button Runat="server" ID="transferButton" cssclass="submit" Text ='<%= string.Format("Save, Close & Transfer {0}", returnDynamicText())%>'/>
```

So far I only get the string.format statement text displayed in the button control, "<%= string.Format("Save, Close & Transfer {0}", returnDynamicText())%>". This is the dynamic formatted text I actually need, "Save, Close and Transfer Dynamic Text" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a databinding expression

```
Text='<%# string.Format("Save, Close & Transfer {0}", returnDynamicText()) %>' />
```

And if the button is not inside a Repeater, GridView etc you need to call `DataBind()` in `Page_Load`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I changed the <%= to a <%# and made sure I had the DataBind() call in the Page_Load(). It is now working perfectly. This is a great working solution.